# Cannot Assign the variables of a function to the Labels on Swift

Tags: swift

I am working on an app that Decode a JSON file and creates three variables out of the function: **Status**,**emptySlots**,**freeBikes**. I want to assign these values to labels. However, no matter what I do, I was unable to get any output with any method.

The function code:

```
func getBikeData(stationName:String){

    if let url = URL(string: "https://api.citybik.es//v2/networks/baksi-bisim"){
   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
           guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else {
           print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
           return
       }
       do {
           //here dataResponse received from a network request
           let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                                  dataResponse, options: [])
           print(jsonResponse) //Response result


           do {
               //here dataResponse received from a network request
               let decoder = JSONDecoder()
               //Decode JSON Response Data

            let model = try decoder.decode(ResponseJSON.self, from: dataResponse)
            print(model)//Output - 1221

            if let station = model.network.stations.first(where: { $0.name == stationName }) {
            //get the properties of station here as per requirement
                let emptySlots: Int = station.empty_slots
                let freeBikes: Int = station.free_bikes
                let Status: String = station.extra.status
                print(emptySlots, freeBikes, Status)
            }

           }
           catch let parsingError {
               print("Error", parsingError)
           }

        } catch let parsingError {
           print("Error", parsingError)
        }


   }
   task.resume()

 }
}
```

Any help is gladly appreciated. I have already tried to return the variables, and using completion block.

ResponseJSON Struct:

```
struct ResponseJSON: Codable {
        let network: Stations
    }
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: And you ResponseJSON class?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61605231/11973420

Comment: @elliott-io When I try to return the variable as an output : "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"

Comment: *When I try to return the variable as an output*. The code doesn't **return** anything.

Comment: Ok, can you post your `ResponseJSON` class?

Comment: @vadian The output that needs to be assigned is **Status,emptySlots,freeBikes**. when I try to do `func getBikeData(stationName:String)->(emptySlots:Int,freeBikes:Int,Status:String){  return(emptySlots,freeBikes,Status)`

Comment: You have to add a completion handler or – simpler – assign the values to the labels directly inside the completion closure of the data task (instead of creating the variables).

Comment: @vadian I tried the same method which caused a problem when declaring the function.

Comment: The method cannot have a return value. As I said assign the values to the labels directly.

Comment: @vadian I put `self.label.text= Status` on the body of the code, I recieved the error "UILabel.text must be used from main thread only"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use a closure. To simplify things create a struct that holds the values

```
struct BikeResponse {
    let status: String
    let freeBikes: Int
    let emptySlots: Int
}
```

And then modify your function declaration to

```
func getBikeData(stationName:String, completion: (BikeResponse)->(Void)){
```

and then after the decoding you call the completion handler

```
if let station = model.network.stations.first(where: { $0.name == stationName }) {
    let response = BikeResponse(status: station.extra.status,
                                freeBikes: station.free_bikes,
                                emptySlots: station.empty_slots)
    completion(response)
```

And then in your completion code you can assign the values to your labels

```
getBikeData(stationName: "ABC") { response in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
     someLabel.text = response.status
     //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Error Message "UILabel.text must be used from main thread only"

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution:

```
if let station = model.network.stations.first(where: { $0.name == stationName }) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.emptySlotsLabel.text = String(station.empty_slots)
        self.freeBikesLabel.text = String(station.free_bikes)
        self.statusLabel.text = station.extra.status
    }
}
```

`emptySlotsLabel`, `freeBikesLabel` and `statusLabel` are the labels, change the names to the real names

Comment: Error Message UILabel.text must be used from main thread only

Comment: This is impossible since my code **does** assign the values on the main thread.

Comment: you can check the code on github.com/utkut/MapKitTest

Comment: The code on GitHub is the same as in the question. Have you ever tried my suggestion?

Comment: You cannot get the *main thread* error with the `DispatchQueue.main` block.

Comment: I am so sorry vadian, I missed the dispatch queue part of the code, It just worked now. You saved my hours!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add completion handler to you function. Because you are trying to make async query. 
After calling getbikedata func you can assign value to your labels.
Sample code looks like this:

```
func getBikeData(stationName:String, completion: @escaping (Station) -> Void) {
// ... your code here
        if let station = model.network?.stations?.first(where: { $0.name == stationName }) {
            //get the properties of station here as per requirement
            // let emptySlots: Int = station.emptySlots!
            // let freeBikes: Int = station.freeBikes!
            // let Status: String = (station.extra?.status)!.rawValue
            completion(station)
        }
// ... other your code here
}
```

And usage:

```
getBikeData(stationName: stationName) { (station) in
    print(station)
    // For example
    label.text = station.emptySlots
}
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'moreDetail.Station' to expected argument type 'moreDetail.BikeResponse' Error Message